# Manually replicating AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas to load only select Areas?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm quite new to ASP.NET and I was thinking of a way to create multiple Frontend Areas for different themes. But the Area Routes would collide so I need to manually load the relevant Area that I want to use as the active Frontend Theme.

I'd like different Areas and not just sets of Views that would share Models and Controllers *(easily achieved with custom RazorViewEngine)* as Models / Controllers might differ radically for each individual Theme.

Can this be done? Or can I do this in another way?

So instead of `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas` I'd like to register the Backend Area and one of the Frontend areas *(even if multiple are available)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Having had little success of getting an answer, decided to post my solution here and sadly answer my own question.*

Given the volatile load order of the `AreaRegistrations`, I ended up replacing the `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` with:

```
static void RegisterArea<AR>(RouteCollection routes, object state)
    where AR : AreaRegistration
{
    var registration = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(AR)) as AreaRegistration;
    var context = new AreaRegistrationContext(registration.AreaName, routes, state);
    var namespaceset = registration.GetType().Namespace;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(namespaceset))
    {
        // Important to relatively resolve Controllers
        context.Namespaces.Add(namespaceset + ".*");
    }
    registration.RegisterArea(context);
}
```

This is how I used the code:

```
RegisterArea<Areas.Backend.BackendAreaRegistration>(RouteTable.Routes, null);
RegisterArea<Areas.Frontend.FrontendAreaRegistration>(RouteTable.Routes, null);
```

This allows you to decide the order of the `Areas` manually. Especially useful when you have `{*anything}` directive in `Frontend` routes that might end up loaded before the `Backend` routes.